# How can I reset the default .bat file handler in Windows Vista?

Tags: windows-vista, file-association, default-settings

I make a mistake one day: I made notepad the default application for opening `.bat` files. I've tried using `cmd.exe` to open a `.bat` file, but all it does is open a new window; it doesn't execute the script. How can I restore the default behavior for batch files? I'm using Windows Vista.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download and install [Creative Element Power Tools](http://www.creativelement.com/powertools/).
2. Open the Creative Element Power Tools Control Panel.
3. Turn on the Edit file type associations option, and click Accept.
4. Right-click a file of the type you want to change, and select Edit File Type to show this window:

[image]

Highlight **.bat** and remove it.

Comment: I had to create a new one, but the default settings seams to have worked, thanks

Comment: you're more than welcome.